# Read unicoded text from file not correctly, missing space, wrong character

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, fonts, terminal

I'm cleaning text of a .txt file. However, after reading the file, I found that the text is missing space and wrong character between only some words.

I'm using Python 3 and the text is in Vietnamese.

```
Orignial text: "vui lòng cởi đồ ra tôi muốn nghe khám bệnh"
```

```py
In[1]: with open('test.txt') as f:
          read_text = f.read()
       read_text
Out[1] vui lòng cởi đô`ra tôi muốn nghe khám bệnh
```

Look closely at "đồ ra" -> "đô`ra". A character "ồ" became two characters: "ô" and "`".

And when I used `re` to remove all special characters

```py
In[2]: import re
       read_text = re.sub('\W+',' ',read_text)
       read_text
Out[2]: vui lo ng cơ i đô ra tôi muô n nghe kha m bê nh
```

The result should be the same as the original but NO. What is wrong?

Comment: I think you need to include the encoding.Try this `with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8'). Check this page for python standard encodings https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

Comment: This might be related to the font used to render text in your terminal - not all fonts handle composed characters correctly.  Try some other, unicode-friendly fonts and see if they render the text correctly.

Comment: @Nick I've tried but it's still not work.

Comment: @AnhQuýLêGia The character in question is a composite character. If you copy it (ồ) and hit backspace once, you'll notice that ô stays. Both characters displaying side-by-side is a side effect of your console not handling \` composite with ô correctly. The re example doesn't work as intended because other characters with \` above are also composite but displayed correctly by your console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the Python language - 
the thing is that the particular character you are pointing at, and possibly others, have two combining diacritical marks. And the problem is that not all text dealing applications can handle that. I myself am using a Qt-based terminal where pasting the first string in your question simply "does away" with the second diacritical - the "`" marking,leaving only "ô". (A GTK+ based terminal handles it correctly, though).

So the thing is that the unicode string presented by Python is correct. The terminal application you are using to see it can't handle it right, and place two diacriticals on the same character, though.

Filtering diacriticals away from unicode characters is almost never the "right thing to do". If your app is to support Vietnamese text, it should do it correctly, not silently converting some characters.

For "western based" languages, where letters will usually have one diacritical that is quite easier - not only the terminal and output libraries support then fine, but also, usually all characters are represented by a single unicode-codepoint.

When one moves to needing more diacriticals per character, though, you loose the equivalence of "one character in the string" equals "one character on screen" (regardless of the output being correct). And then you have to worry about that in your code.

If you are simply indexing things for search, and even a text corpus for training, it may be ok to strip diacriticals, but then, maybe, you should strip all of them.

The way to do that is to force the string into a normalized Unicode representation, in which all diacriticals are represented as separate "combining characters" instead of composed characters, and then filter out only the letter characters;

```
import unicodedata
a = "vui lòng cởi đồ ra tôi muốn nghe khám bệnh"

# Normalize the internal representation:
b = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", a)
print(*(c for c in b), sep=" ")
# outputs: "v u i   l o ̀ n g   c o ̛ ̉ i   đ o ̂ ̀   r a   t o ̂ i   m u o ̂ ́ n   n g h e   k h a ́ m   b e ̣ ̂ n h"

# recreates the string filtering out combining characters:
c = "".join(c for c in b if unicodedata.category(c) != "Mn")
print(c)
# outputs: 'vui long coi đo ra toi muon nghe kham benh'
```